# Faster RCNN training get stuck in iteration 660

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection

I met one problem where I trained py-faster-rcnn on my own dataset, but it get stuck in iteration 660 for a long time and no response. Has anyone met this problem before? How to solve it? Thanks a lot!

FYR:

> ```
> I0404 17:50:23.514286 25601 solver.cpp:571] Iteration 640, lr = 0.001
> I0404 17:50:24.876749 25601 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 660, loss = 0.341694
> I0404 17:50:24.876804 25601 solver.cpp:258] Train net output #0: rpn_cls_loss = 0.296529 (* 1 = 0.296529 loss)
> I0404 17:50:24.876819 25601 solver.cpp:258] Train net output #1: rpn_loss_bbox = 0.0451643 (* 1 = 0.0451643 loss)
> I0404 17:50:24.876835 25601 solver.cpp:571] Iteration 660, lr = 0.001
> ```

Comment: Hi, @Shai, Do you why this happened or is there a way to find out what the problem is?

Comment: I am not very familiar with r-cnn training procedure, you might want to add debug prints in the python modules to see what is going on.

Comment: have you try to print more information when training? maybe it get stuck when loading annotation? or maybe something setting error when initializing?